# Identify when scene is finished loading in Maya

Tags: c++, events, plugins, maya

I am writing a Maya plugin in c++.

In Maya, when opening a scene, my plugin is loaded automatically and started.
Is there an event that tells my plugin that the whole scene is loaded so I can start some actions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
callbackId = MSceneMessage::addCallback(MSceneMessage::kAfterOpen,  (MMessage::MBasicFunction) BrainClass::sceneLoaded,this);
myCallbackIds.append(callbackId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the Maya C++ API but there is a mal/python solution that may suit your needs. I know this question is tagged C++ so I'll remove it if this is not an acceptable answer.

There is a `scriptJob` command in the maya.cmds mel/python library that allows to bind the execution of a code when an event or condition happens in Maya.

```
def printStuff():
    # We are printing stuff here, but this can be a call to your C++ plugin
    # Example:
    # import cppPlugin
    # cppPlugin.doActionOnSceneLoaded()
    print "Scene has been loaded"

cmds.scriptJob(e=('SceneOpened', printStuff))
```

Once this code is executed, every time your open a scene, once it's fully loaded this will print a line. Instead of printing a line you can do a call to your C++ Plugin. My C++ skills a rusty by now, it's been a while I havn't practised but you can bind C++ methods to a Python call, you can get some infos [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages) and [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/SimpleExample).

You can write this script in `userSetup.py`to load it when Maya is launched. You can get more informations on userSetup files [here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/Python_Python_in_Maya.htm,topicNumber=d30e725143)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:`!MFileIO::isReadingFile()`

Comment: Where would you place this code?